# How to change color of scatterplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2, how could I change the color of coloring in scatter plot?

Answer (score 12):

Here's a small dataset:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=1:20,
                  y=rnorm(20,0,10),
                  v=20:1)
```

Suppose I want my points colored using the value v.  I can change the way in which the coloring is performed using the [scale_colour_gradient()](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/scale_gradient.html) function.

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x,y,data=dat,colour=color,size=4) + 
  scale_colour_gradient(low="black", high="white")
```

[image]

This example should just get you started.  For more, check out the `scale_brewer()` mentioned in the other post.

Answer (score 9):

check out the ggplot documentation for scale_brewer http://www.had.co.nz/ggplot2/scale_brewer.html

some examples:

```
#see available pallets:

library(RColorBrewer)
display.brewer.all(5)

#scatter plot
dsamp <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ] 
d <- qplot(carat, price, data=dsamp, colour=clarity)
dev.new()
d
dev.new()
d + scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")
dev.new()
d + scale_colour_brewer(palette="Blues")
```

Answer (score 8):

If your data have discrete categories that you wish to colour, then your task is a bit easier. For example, if your data look like this, with each row representing a transaction,

```
> d <- data.frame(customer = sample(letters[1:5], size = 20, replace = TRUE),
>                sales = rnorm(20, 8000, 2000),
>                profit = rnorm(20, 40, 15))
> head(d,6)
customer    sales   profit
        a 8414.617 15.33714
        a 8759.878 61.54778
        e 8737.289 56.85504
        d 9516.348 24.60046
        c 8693.642 67.23576
        e 7291.325 26.12234
```

and you want to make a scatter plot of transactions coloured by customer, then you can do this

```
p <- ggplot(d, aes(sales,profit))
p + geom_point(aes(colour = customer))
```

to get....

[image: sales vs profit coloured on customer]